# error when using the import scanner

Tags: java

this is from an intro to programming class, unfortunatley my instructor is not helpful at all, so im seeking some help from the pros. Im using the latest JDK version. Thanks to anyone that can help.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //the error here reads : incorrect package. but im in the correct package

package calculate.a.tip.ricardo.penaloza; // the error here reads: class,interface or enum expected

public class CalculateATipRicardoPenaloza 
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number for radius");
        double radius = input.nextDouble();

        double area = radius * radius * 3.14;

        System.out.println("The area for the circle of radius" +
                radius + "is" + area);
    }

}

Error: Could not find or load main class calculate.a.tip.ricardo.penaloza.CalculateATipRicardoPenaloza
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `package` declaration must come before any `import` statements or `class` declarations.

Comment: is this not a package declaration ? package calculate.a.tip.ricardo.penaloza;

Comment: @user1066367 Yes, that is a package declaration.